# How to show logged user's username on a label placed in another form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am at beginner level in C#. And I am creating courier service assignment.

I have created a database table for login with 2 fields, username and password. if the entered username and password is correct, it shows another form(WELCOME Form) and if it is not correct, it shows an error message in label.

There is a LOGIN Form and a WELCOME Form for the data Entry Operator. When data Entry Operator logged in to his account, the Welcome form should appear and there is a label, which displays HIS username.

Now my question is, that when a user logged in to his account, what coding should I use to display logged user's username in Welcome Form's label?

I tried doing this with dataset but it only shows the first record(data).

It would be greatly appreciated, if somebody help me.

Comment: I am talking about winforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide logged user name through WelcomeForm constructor:

```
public WelcomForm(string userName)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    userNameLabel.Text = userName;
}
```

Also use a property on LoginForm to get logged in user name:

```
public string UserName // on LoginForm
{
    get { return userNameTextBox.Text; }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    return;

WelcomForm welcomeForm = new WelcomeForm(loginForm.UserName);
welcomeForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Can you please explain this if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    return;

Comment: @user3193652 usually you check if provided credentials are valid, and then set `DialogResult` of `LoginForm` to `OK` if credentials are valid, or `Cancel` if use was not logged in.

Comment: I used    
   public WelcomForm(string userName)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    userNameLabel.Text = userName;
}

in welcome form and all other in login form but when I run this, it opens another login form even after logged in. and it does not show username on welcome form. –

Comment: It is done. I was putting it separately rather I have to put it there, where I was displaying a form, when the user logged in. Thank you